# ARIMA visualization in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dashboard, arima

I wanna use PowerBI-visuals-forcasting-ARIMA.1.2.1.0 for sale forecasting but it just predicts about 4 or 5 days in the future. how I can change the setting to predict some months later?

Answer (score 0):

In format tab --->forcasting settings we can change settings like forecast length, confidence level, and ...